# AWS DMS VS Oracle Golden Gate for object names (over 30 bytes)

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, dms, oracle-golden-gate

I am planning to use AWS DMS to migrate Oracle data with the CDC option. It has a limitation on "AWS DMS doesn't support long object names (over 30 bytes)". As renaming the column will impact Datamodel and code changes, so i can't opt for that.

I tried research on Oracle Golden Gate but was not able to find any similar limitations or not.

Do we have any other options to migrate data with real-time data availability for the Oracle database?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this isn't Golden Gate's limitation, but rather Oracle database's.

[Identifier Name Length and Uniqueness](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/EFCoreIdentifier.html#GUID-FA43F1A1-EDA2-462F-8844-45D49EF67607) specifies that

> Oracle Database prior to version 12.2 limit identifier names, such as table names, column names, and primary key names, to 30 characters. Oracle Database 12.2 and higher have a default limit of 128 characters.

Furthermore, [Limitations on using Oracle as a source for AWS DMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.Oracle.html#CHAP_Source.Oracle.Limitations) says (among other *limitations*)

> AWS DMS doesn't support long object names (over 30 bytes).

That's just how it is; implementation is such that it won't support names longer than 30 bytes.

---

I never did what you're trying to do, but it seems that the whole process wasn't *scanned* in details because you **first** set data model (which uses *long* object names), and **then** decided to perform migration which can't be done due to "wrong" decision in the 1st step.

What to do? I'm afraid that option you already know:

> As renaming the column will impact Datamodel and code changes, so i can't opt for that.

is the one. Would I want to do that? Certainly not! But, what *can* you do? No idea; someone else might have it, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, "AWS DMS doesn't support long object names (over 30 bytes)" i am not sure this limitation if from AWS or Oracle. As we already have column names with > 30 chars and trying to avoid code changes, i am thinking of suggesting Oracle Golden Gate if it has not limit on column names.

Comment: I sincerely hope & wish you won't have to change anything in data model or code; I just don't know what "option" to set (nor where) so that you'd be able to do it.